# Generic for-loop: Is there a way to get iteration information?

Tags: java, loops

I am used to implement loops with generics like that:

```
for (final Dog lDog : lAllDog) {
   ...
}
```

Unfortunality for another business case I need the current count of the iteration.
I know I can solve this by coding somthing like that:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < lAllDog.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
for (final Dog lDog : lAllDog) {
   ...
   i++;
}
```

but is there a way to get the current count of iteration with my first code example without declaring a new `int` or change the whole loop header?

Thx a lot

Comment: The enhanced for loop does not have a counter - so you need to introduce a counter, one way or another. Your 2 examples pretty much covered the possibilies...

Comment: I view the enhanced for-loop as being specialized for some specific, very simple, very commonly occurring cases. I use it for those. For anything else, there is nothing wrong with the old for loop.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan the enhanced for loop uses an `Iterator` under the hood this means it traverses all collections at an optimal rate. The "old `for` loop" has two issues - it cannot traverse a `Set` and if you try to traverse a `LinkedList` you end up with horrible performance.

Comment: @bmorris591 Any enhanced for-loop has scan either an array or an Iterable. Arrays can be scanned efficiently by int index. An Iterable has an iterator() method that returns an Iterator, and so can be scanned by an explicitly Iterator-based basic for statement. It is important to remember that a basic for statement does not have be entirely index-based - that is an option in appropriate cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly, no. You have to use the indexing method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other to get count of iteration other than you described in your question. You'll have to use old way to have counter defined

Answer (score 1):

No. The enhanced for loop doesn't hold an index. You'll have to introduce it yourself if you want one.

The reason is because it's based on [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. Essentially, it uses an iterator to loop through a collection.

Answer (score 1):

No, if your list has unique elements

May be you can try this

```
for (final Dog lDog : lAllDog) {

 int i=  lAllDog.indexOf(lDog);
}
```

Comment: Note that this moves your algorithm from `O(n)` to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @recursive just provided alternative..Thanks for reply

Comment: This is not a good approach because the `indexOf()` will iterate through the list each time making this code slow with O(n**2).

Comment: @dsh I know and already recursive tell that,  Why posting answer "No" Which already posted by other, just for a change showing alternative..Thanks for reply

Comment: Even though this is O(n^2), but it is  definitely correct. You shouldn't make any assumption on the order of a collection. only indexOf() will give you the correct index.

Comment: @Pragnani Why?  Not all readers of your answer will recognize the algorithmic performance impact so I was simply explaining that.  There were no comments when I started writing, so it occurred that we wrote at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

They say every problem in computer science can be solved by more indirection

```
class Indexed<T>
    int index;
    T value;

static <T> Iterable<Indexed<T>> indexed(Iterable<T> iterable){ ... }

for(Indexed<Dog> idog : indexed(dogs))
    print(idog.index);
    print(idog.value);
```

In java 8, we probably want to abstract this control pattern as

```
forEach(dogs, (index, dog)->{ 
    print(index);
    print(dog);
});

static <T> void forEach(Iterable<T> collections, Acceptor<T> acceptor){...}

interface Acceptor<T>
    void accept(int index, T value);
```

Comment: nice solution but looks a little bit oversized for my requirement.

Comment: This would still use one of the code snippets from the question, hidden in the `indexed()` method, and double the amount of objects, so it seems like some unnecessary overhead.

Comment: It might be worthwhile if you want to do this a lot, however